# How to get common factors with c++?

Tags: c++, c

I'm having trouble starting with the code i have already read some other questions here but im still stuck on how am i even gonna start this one :/.

So i made 3 inputs to fill the expression (ax^2+bx+c)

```
.......
        cout<<"This Program runs onlyy the expression (ax^2+bx+c)"<<endl;
        cout<<"\nEnter The first Integer[a]";
        cin>>ina;
        cout<<"Enter the second Integer[b]";
        cin>>inb;
        cout<<"Enter The third Integer[c]";
        cin>>inc;

        cout<<"Your Expression is"<<endl;
        cout<<ina<<"x^2 + "<<inb<<"x + "<<inc<<endl;
........
```

Now how would i make my program show its common factor..
example is `(x^2+4x+3)` how can i make it show that its common factor is `(x+3) and (x+1)`?

Answer (score 2):

Well **how to factor a polynomial** has very little to do with C++.

If `Ax^2 + Bx + C` can be expressed as `A*(x - x1)*(x - x2)` (and it can always be so expressed), then clearly plugging the value `x1` in for `x` makes the original equation zero, since the first term of `(x1 - x1)*(x1 - x2)` is then 0. And ditto for `x2`. And conversely, if you have two values that make the equation zero, then they are `x1` and `x2`.

There is a standard formula for solving quadratic equations. Computing that in a program one should be aware that subtracting a number from a roughly equal size number can produce a less precise result. So how that formula is expressed in the code, can make a difference wrt. to the accuracy of the results. You can find more information about that on the net. Including examples for quadratic equation formula.